# Insert an HTML icon within a Javascript new div

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

In this Django project, there is a Javascript function creating a new div in which we display some data.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        newDiv.setAttribute("class","files_div");
        //Call the helper function to check if it's a PDF
        newDiv.setAttribute("onclick","check_files(this)")
        console.log(files[i]) //Print the files
        newDiv.innerHTML = files[i];
        divParent.appendChild(newDiv);
    }
```

I need to add icons next to this data. For example, a pdf icon if it's a pdf file.
How do you add icons in Javascript once a new div is created?

Comment: Have you tried creating an img element and setting its src attribute, the same way you did with the div and its class and onclick attributes?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you mean like appending the image to an HTML div? I have tried this <img src="{% static '/icons/road-1.svg' %}" alt="" class="runway"> . But since the HTML div is not the same as the div in javascript. The image doesn't appear in the correct place. I need to append this image to "files_div" created in Javascript.

Comment: You'd need to append your img to the div the same way you append your div to the divParent. `newDiv.appendChild(newIcon);`

Comment: Thank you but it gives an error ("The new icon is not defined"). :)

Comment: Please post what you tried that produced that error. Can't debug it without seeing it.

Comment: Great idea! I will do that next time. I went with the solution below and it worked, so I don't have the previous code anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a css-based solution on this? You can add an icon to any element using pseudo elements. This adds another element next to `.pdf` which you can style to fit your purpose. Using `background-image` allows you to add an icon.

```css
.pdf {
  padding-left: 35px;
  position: relative;
}

.pdf:before {
  content: "";
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  display: block;
  background: url("https://via.placeholder.com/20");
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="pdf">PDF</div>
```